# Add/Remove inputs dynamically jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

I'm trying to add and remove some inputs dynamically using JavaScript. I have a button with id *nuevaPartida*, when it is clicked call an event which adds two inputs type text (*producto[]* and *cantidad[]*) and two labels.

This group (of input fields and labels) is added without any problem, the problem is when I try to remove groups  clicking the button with id *quitaPartida*. It only removes the last group added and when I click again nothing else Is removed, I mean, the action works just once and I need to get remove **one group by click** .

**HTML**

```
<div class="partidas">
    <div class="masDatos">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 masProductos">
             {!!Form::label('Producto')!!}
             {!!Form::select('producto[]', $almacenes, null, ['class' => 'form-control select2', 'data-placeholder' => 'SELECCIONE UN PRODUCTO', 'style' => 'width: 100%', 'id'=>'sproducto0'])!!}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 masCantidad">
            {!!Form::label('Cantidad')!!}
            {!!Form::text('cantidad[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Ej. 5', 'data-inputmask'=>'"mask": "999"', 'data-mask', 'id' => 'cantidad'])!!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
<script>
    var template =  '<div class="masDatos">'+
                        '<div class="form-group col-md-6 masProductos">'+
                          '{!!Form::label('Producto')!!}'+
                          '{!!Form::select('producto[]', $almacenes, null, ['class' => 'form-control select2', 'data-placeholder' => 'SELECCIONE UN PRODUCTO', 'style' => 'width: 100%', 'id'=>'sproducto0'])!!}'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '<div class="form-group col-md-6 masCantidad">'+
                          '{!!Form::label('Cantidad')!!}'+
                          '{!!Form::text('cantidad[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Ej. 5', 'data-inputmask'=>'"mask": "999"', 'data-mask', 'id' => 'cantidad'])!!}'+
                        '</div>'+
                      '</div>';

    $('#nuevaPartida').on('click', function(e){
      //$('.partidas').append(template);
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.partidas').before(template);
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#quitaPartida', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.partidas').children('.masDatos').remove();
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: use `.each(function(){$(this).remove();})` on the `$('.partidas').children('.masDatos')`

Comment: I just seen the OP edit after post my answer and now I think you're looking for something different than we have thought, can you explain it better? What do you mean by "_one element by click_"? What element do you mean exactly?

Comment: By the way, I've noticed that you use spanish words in your code. Maybe you want to check [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: "_It only removes the last group added and I need to get remove one group by click_". If it is not the last one, if they are not all of them, what group do you want to remove exactly?

Comment: Sorry, the problem Is that the remove action only removes the last group once, so, when I click to remove again, it doesn't works anymore.

Comment: Can you setup a jsfiddle demonstrating the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you're inserting the dynamic content *before* the target div (`.partidas`). So your commented line do the job correctly, since you want to append the content to the target div. Uncomment the line, remove the wrong one and it's solved.

Working snippet (https://jsfiddle.net/vhdw3v7j/):

```js
var template =  '<div class="masDatos">'+
    '<div class="form-group col-md-6 masProductos">'+
    'foo <input type="text">' +
    '</div>'+
    '<div class="form-group col-md-6 masCantidad">'+
    'foo <input type="text">' +
    '</div>'+
    '</div>';

$('#nuevaPartida').on('click', function(){
  $('.partidas').append(template);
});

$(document).on('click', '#quitaPartida', function(){
  $('.partidas').children('.masDatos').remove();
  // if you want to remove the last added group:
  // $('.partidas').children('.masDatos').last().remove();
});
```

```css
.partidas { color: lightgray; background: gray; }
.masDatos { margin-top: 20px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="nuevaPartida">nueva partida</button>
<button id="quitaPartida">quita partida</button>

<div class="partidas"></div>
```